# Varying image size from batch to batch performance

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm new to pytorch and I just saw that if I use a custom collate_fn for my dataloader, I can pad the input images (which are varying in size) to be the size of the largest image in the batch, and I don't need to pad according to max image size in the whole dataset. My question is, if the size of images changes in each batch, can pytorch still optimize the operations, or would it be faster to pad everything to the same size?

Thanks.

I remember something in tensorlflow, where if the size changed, it had to do a full retrace in the graph which was slow. Is there something similar here?

Comment: It is similar to your experience in TensorFlow.  You should pad out or scale the images to be the same size.

Comment: Have you tried implementing both padding methods and then comparing their speed yourself? That would give you a definitive answer.